# Unable to select text in custom EditText subclass

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I'm trying to create my own subclass of EditText, but I ran into issues where I lost a lot of functionality that the original EditText had and I'm not sure why. The EditText doesn't respond to long presses, and the cursor can't be moved backward without using backspace. The keyboard was also not opening when the EditText was selected, but I was able to find a workaround for that problem using the InputMethodManager.

Here's the code for my EditText class:

```
import android.content.Context
import android.graphics.Canvas
import android.graphics.Paint
import android.util.AttributeSet
import android.widget.EditText
import android.animation.ObjectAnimator
import android.text.*
import android.util.Log
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat
import android.view.KeyEvent
import com.changeroom.android.R
import android.util.TypedValue
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT
import kotlin.math.roundToInt


class FloatingHintEditText : EditText {

    //controls whether or not hints are displayed in all caps
    private var hintCaps = false

    //how much space to leave at bottom of edittext
    private val bottomSpacing = resources.getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.inner_components_spacing)

    //controls the color of error message text
    private var errorColor = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.errorRed)

    //controls the size of the error message
    private val bottomTextSize = 0.75f

    //stores the text to go underneath
    var bottomText: CharSequence? = null
        private set

    //controls the style of the floating hint
    private val hintPaint = Paint().apply {
        this.color = (this@FloatingHintEditText).currentHintTextColor
        this.textSize = (this@FloatingHintEditText).textSize
        this.typeface = (this@FloatingHintEditText).typeface
        this.strokeWidth = 2f
    }

    //controls the style of the bottom text
    private val bottomTextPaint = TextPaint().apply {
        this.color = errorColor
        this.textSize = (this@FloatingHintEditText).textSize * 0.75f
        this.typeface = (this@FloatingHintEditText).typeface
    }

    //stores whether the text is a password field
    private var isPassword =
        inputType and InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_VARIATION_PASSWORD == InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_VARIATION_PASSWORD
                || inputType and InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD == InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD
                || inputType and InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_WEB_PASSWORD == InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_WEB_PASSWORD


    //stores values for animating
    private val errorAnimDuration = 100L
    private val focusAnimDuration = 100L
    var floatingLabelFraction = 1f
    var hintSize = 1f
    var mainColorController = currentHintTextColor
    var errorHeight = 1f
    private val errorFocusAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(this, "errorHeight", 1f, 0f).apply {
        duration = errorAnimDuration
    }
    private val labelFocusAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(this, "floatingLabelFraction", 1f, 0f).apply {
        duration = focusAnimDuration
    }
    private val labelSizeAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(this, "hintSize", 1f, 0.75f).apply {
        duration = focusAnimDuration
    }

    constructor(context: Context) : super(context)
    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) : super(context, attrs) {
        initializeAttrs(attrs)
    }
    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet, defStyleAttr: Int) : super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {
        initializeAttrs(attrs)
    }

    private fun initializeAttrs(attrs: AttributeSet) {
        context.theme.obtainStyledAttributes(
            attrs,
            R.styleable.FloatingHintEditText,
            0, 0).apply {

            try {
                errorColor = getColor(
                    R.styleable.FloatingHintEditText_errorColor, ContextCompat.getColor(context,
                        R.color.errorRed
                    ))
                highlightColor = getColor(
                    R.styleable.FloatingHintEditText_highlightColor, ContextCompat.getColor(context,
                        R.color.colorAccent
                    ))
                hintCaps = getBoolean(
                    R.styleable.FloatingHintEditText_hintCaps, false
                )
            } finally {
                bottomTextPaint.color = errorColor
                recycle()
            }
        }
    }

    init {
        setPadding(paddingLeft, paddingTop, paddingRight, getPixel(8) + paddingBottom)

        setOnFocusChangeListener { _, _ ->
            val imm = context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager?
            imm!!.showSoftInput(this, SHOW_IMPLICIT)
            if (text.isNotEmpty() || bottomText != null) {
                //do nothing
            }
            else if (isFocused) {
                labelSizeAnimator.start()
                labelFocusAnimator.start()
            } else {
                labelSizeAnimator.reverse()
                labelFocusAnimator.reverse()
            }

            if (isFocused && bottomText == null) {
                mainColorController = highlightColor
            }
            else if (bottomText == null) {
                mainColorController = currentHintTextColor
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas?) {

        val startX = scrollX + paddingStart
        val endX = width + scrollX - paddingEnd

        //draw the bottom text (if there is any)
        if (bottomText != null) {
            bottomTextPaint.textSize = textSize * bottomTextSize
            bottomTextPaint.color = mainColorController

            //calculate the position of the bottom message
            val bottomTextStartX = if (layoutDirection == LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL) endX else startX
            val bottomTextStartY = height.toFloat() - errorHeight * textSize * bottomTextSize / 3 - textSize * bottomTextSize / 3

            //draw the bottom message
            canvas?.drawText(bottomText.toString(), bottomTextStartX.toFloat(), bottomTextStartY, bottomTextPaint)
        }

        //set hint/underline colour
        hintPaint.color = mainColorController

        //draw the underline
        val underlineY = height.toFloat() - textSize * bottomTextSize - bottomSpacing
        canvas?.drawLine(startX.toFloat(), underlineY, endX.toFloat(), underlineY, hintPaint)

        hintPaint.textSize = textSize * hintSize

        val hintText = if (hintCaps) hint?.toString()?.toUpperCase() ?: "" else hint?.toString() ?: ""

        // calculate the position of the floating hint
        val floatingLabelStartX: Float = if (layoutDirection == LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL) endX.toFloat() else startX.toFloat()
        val floatingLabelStartY = (height / 2) * floatingLabelFraction + (textSize * hintSize) * (1 - floatingLabelFraction) + scrollY

        //draw the hint
        canvas?.drawText(hintText, floatingLabelStartX, floatingLabelStartY, hintPaint)

        // makes EditText not draw hint
        val tempHint = hint
        hint = null
        super.onDraw(canvas)
        hint = tempHint
    }

    override fun onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec: Int, heightMeasureSpec: Int) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec)
        val width = measuredWidth
        val height = measuredHeight + textSize * 2.2
        setMeasuredDimension(width, height.toInt())
    }

    fun setBottomText(msg: CharSequence?, isError: Boolean) {
        bottomText = msg
        if (isError) {
            if (!isFocused && text?.isEmpty() == true && bottomText != null) {
                labelSizeAnimator.start()
                labelFocusAnimator.start()
            } else if (text?.isEmpty() == true && !isFocused) {
                labelSizeAnimator.reverse()
                labelFocusAnimator.reverse()
            }
            if (bottomText != null) {
                val errorColorAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofArgb(
                    this, "mainColorController",
                    mainColorController, errorColor
                ).apply {
                    duration = errorAnimDuration
                }
                errorColorAnimator.start()
                errorFocusAnimator.start()
            } else {
                val reverseErrorColourAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofArgb(
                    this, "mainColorController",
                    if (isFocused) highlightColor else currentHintTextColor
                ).apply {
                    duration = errorAnimDuration
                }
                reverseErrorColourAnimator.start()
            }
        }
        else {
            mainColorController = currentHintTextColor
        }
    }


    override fun onKeyPreIme(keyCode: Int, event: KeyEvent): Boolean {
        if (event.keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK){
            this.clearFocus()
        }
        return super.onKeyPreIme(keyCode, event)
    }

    private fun getPixel(dp: Int): Int {
        val r = context.resources
        val px = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, dp.toFloat(), r.displayMetrics)
        return px.roundToInt()
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the issue was that I was setting the hint to null before calling super.onDraw(), then resetting it to its previous value. I ended up just creating a separate field to store the floating label and that fixed it for me.